# How to get a value of a textfield in a listview? (Flutter)

Tags: listview, dart, flutter, textfield

I have a listview builder that shows some text fields (the number of items isn't fixed, always it will be variable). There is a button delegate to get all the values of this textfields. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the data in a stateful widget that encloses the `ListView`.

For example your data could be a simple List with one item for each `TextField`.

Use the `onChanged` callback of `TextField` to update the data when the user edits the field.

Answer (score 0):

First define a `List` like so `List<TextEditingController> textFieldControllers=[];`

then iterate through the the list used in creating the widgets in the `List.builder` like so.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < typesItem.length; i++) {
  textFieldControllers.add(TextEditingController());
}
```

where `typesItem` is the List item used in creating the Listbuilder widgets so as to maintain same lenght with your widgets dynamically.You can run this code on your `initState` method
there after goto your List.builder widget and initialise your controller like so.

```
 textFieldControllers[index] =  TextEditingController() ;
```

and set your TextField controllers in your return method like so

```
textFieldControllers[index]
```

You can therefore get all your value by using

```
  textFieldControllers[index].text;
```

You can manipulate to suit use your case as you want